# How to check if a row exist in sql using datagridview column

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to check if a row exist in sql using a datagridview column
I am using these lines of code:

```
    SqlCommand cmdcontrol= new SqlCommand("checkbarcode", conn);
                    cmdcontrol.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdcontrol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", Convert.ToString(tgproduct.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                    int product = (int)cmdcontrol.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (product > 0)
                    {
                        //update qty of product based on barcode (from column index 0)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     //do a insertion process with all details from datagridview
                    }
```

Note that the datagridview may have product that aren't inserted in sql , and products that are inserted in sql and need to update only QTY.
I tested the code to do insertion or update lonely (not both cases in same time) and code works, but when i mix both cases on of the processes isn't done(update or insert process).
I think the problem is in the loop code, where data from datagridview are checked to see if they exist in sql(and based on result the insertion/update process is done).
Could someone help me why when I put a product in datagridview which exist in sql( and need to update qty), and a procut that doesn't exist in sql table(need to insert the product), both process doesn't happen?
Thanks to everyone

Comment: How is this code wired to dgv / other control events? Show all the relevant code.

Comment: the barcoe to check its retrieved from datagridview. In datagridview is a table with product data . Then with a loop function, the program have to check if data from dtg is stored in sql or not.  SqlCommand cmdcontrol= new SqlCommand("checkbarcode", conn);//
                    cmdcontrol.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;//
                    cmdcontrol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", Convert.ToString(tgproduct.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));//
                    int product = (int)cmdcontrol.ExecuteScalar();//